# Spring Exception Handling - @ControllerAdvice cannot handle HttpServletResponse#sendError()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `@ControllerAdvice` to implement a global exception handler but I got some issues with the use of `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` method. 
`@ExceptionHandler` can catch all kinds of exception, but not `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` invocations. I understand that `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` is not an exception, but I need to process it, and then redirect to a generic error page.

I'm using Spring Security for authentication, and in the failed handler, I set status `401` to the response:

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String contentType = request.getContentType();
    logger.info(contentType);
    response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );      
}
```

Then in the `@ControllerAdvice`, I tried to use `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseStatus` to catch `401` but it does not work:

```
@ResponseStatus (value=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, reason="You don't have access right on this page")//401
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public String handleHttpStatus(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
    return "genericerror";
}
```

Can `@ExceptionHandler` methods process `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` invocations?

Comment: is this of any use
http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: yes I referred that post, try to use @ResponseStatus and DataIntegrityViolationException.class but cannot catch the ResponeStatus. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security is a separate framework from Spring MVC. Spring Security is a Servlet filter (have a look in your `web.xml`) which intercepts requests before they reach Spring MVC. You cannot process exceptions that happen at the Spring Security level in `@ControllerAdvice` (as `@ControllerAdvice` is part of Spring MVC).

As you said it yourself, `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` does not throw an exception. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) document, it `sends an error response to the client using the specified status code and clears the buffer.`

In your `web.xml` file you can define static web pages (1) for error response codes and (2) for exceptions. For example:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/errors/genericerror</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to catch HttpServletResponse.sendError(). The method in Spring security is just an example. Thanks to you I understand that ControllerAdvice cannot catch exception thrown by Spring security. However If in some controller, I use HttpServletResponse.sendError() to set error status, can ControllerAdvice catch this? I don't want to use configuration in web.xml because we have a lot of HTTP status, we cannot add configuration for all of them

Comment: @user44858 If you want to process errors that happen in your controllers with `@ExceptionHandler` methods, you have to throw exceptions instead of calling `HttpServletResponse#sendError()`. See the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) for details on exception handling with `@ExceptionHandler` methods.